# How to encode a text with Affine Cipher Using char array alphabet?

Tags: c++, arrays, encoding

My assignment is basicly encoding a user entered text with affine cipher.

> Affine cipher basicly takes a and b keywords and a text for encoding then encodes it using this formula **y = A*x+B mod 26** for each letter of text. **X = Letter**, **Y= Encoded Letter**. **mod26 is for 26 letters of the alphabet**

My assignment is basicly encoding a user entered text with affine cipher.

Here is my code for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string encryption(string message,int a, int b)
{
    string encryptedMessage= "";
    for (int x = 0; x < message.length(); x++)
    {
        encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage + (char) ((((a * message[x]) + b) % 26) + 65);
    }
    return encryptedMessage;
}

int main()
{
   int a,b;
    cout<<"Enter keyword a."<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter keyword b."<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    string text;
    cout<<"Enter the text you want to encrypt"<<endl;
    cin>>text;
    cout<<encryption(text,a,b);
}
```

NOTE:Excuse my english and grammer mistakes.

But this program use ASCII characters and its English alphabet but i need to use Turkish Alphabet but since i can't use ASCII for that i created my own alphabet with array.

```
char alphabet[29]={'A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','Ğ','H','I','İ','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','Ş','T','U','Ü','V','Y','Z'};
```

My question is  basicly **how can i implement this alphabet to my string encryption(string message,int a, int b) function ?** I tried to use for loop for some lame algorithm like : For each latter in message(entered by user) if letters equal to char alphabet array pick them then create Word in a array called **Word** but i think its too lame since i also have to throw that array into that **encryption** function then encrypt it with a lot of for loops.so an you help me with this ?

NOTE:Sorry for my grammar mistakes.

Comment: Your array declaration is for [30] characters, but I can count only 28 - is something missing?

Comment: @TodorSimeonov compeletyl my mistake sorry. I was testing code and forgot the fix it its actually 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this alphabet, encryption method should be:

```
char alphabet[29]={'A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','Ğ','H','I','İ','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','Ş','T','U','Ü','V','Y','Z'};
//This encriptation is using only the fisrt 26 characters 

string encryption(string message,int a, int b)
{
    string encryptedMessage= "";
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < message.length(); x++)
    {
        encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage + alphabet[(((a * (message[x]-64)) + b) % 29)];
    }
    return encryptedMessage;
}
```

Explanation: `(((a * (message[x]-64)) + b) % 29)` this goes from 0 to 28.
`alphabet[(((a * (message[x]-64)) + b) % 29)]`  this acces the specified character from the `char[]`

**Edit:** I also substract `64` (ASCII of `'A'`) to `message[x]`, in order to map `'A'` to the init of array, but it should be used only for ASCII greter than `64`

**Edit2:** If you don´t want this restriction, you can add a number, instead of subtracting, for example if you add `0` or `28` `BBB` gives you `HHH` (ascii of `B` is `66`, and `66*1+1= 67`, then `67%29=9` then `alphabet[9]=H`), but you want `"ÇÇÇ"`, `alphabet[3]=Ç`, so `9-3=6`, and `28-6=22`, so `22` is your magic number.

```
alphabet[(((a * (message[x])) + b + 22) % 29)]
```

Live example using `wchat_t` in [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GTRzbTi5qn37qrHE)

Comment: Thank you it worked. Forgot the fix that array size actually 29 so it should be % 29 but i think its not important. But also something is wrong. O n my previous code it was encoding perfectly but know its not right for example when i enter text as "BBB" and a=1, b=1 it gives me "HHH" instead of "ÇÇÇ" since 1*1+1 mod 29 == 2 so 'B+2' = 'Ç' do you know why ? Do i need to convert the elements of array into int or something like that ?

Comment: @onurcevik actually ascii of  `B` is `66`, and `66*1+1= 67`, then `67%29=9` then `alphabet[9]=H`

Comment: oh thank you but is there a way to use array values instead of ASCII values because that was also one of the reasons why i created alphabet array.

Comment: @onurcevik this ascii values  are from your input string,  you have nothing to do with that. but maybe you can change the formula to adapt to your desired result. For example: `alphabet[(((a * (message[x])) + b + 22) % 29)]` This could give you the desired output

Comment: Thank you. Accepted as answer.Sorry for asking too many questions but what does that 22 value do ? Code is working but i didnt understand how.

Comment: @onurcevik Thanks! I edited the answer, I substract 64 to message[x], in order to map 'A' to the init of array

Comment: @onurcevik added explanation to the body for `22`, hope explain myself well

Comment: OK thanks for explaining it but the problem is it doesn't work for entire alphabet for me also it gives me strange letters probably because i use Turkish alphabet.Since the problem was implementing alphabet into my formula i accepted your reply as answer.But my problems isnt over.Should i create another question for this problem ?

Comment: @onurcevik maybe you can add a new post only for print turkish characters only, with a minimal example. I assumed that was already working on your example for your system

Comment: @onurcevik BTW, try using `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");` before print example: http://ideone.com/8AU7Gp